# Styling the middle text of Chart.js's doughnut chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have exhausted all searches and cannot seem to find my answer.  I'd like to style the text (not tooltips) within the middle of doughnut chart.

I have created it from Chart.js and have a number in the middle (a percentage).  All works well except that I seemingly cannot style the text.  I've tried Canvas' ctx to alter the font as well as css and am having no luck.  Could someone please help me out with this?  Thanks.

My code for the doughnut chart is:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/ed_stats", function (ed_stats) {
      $(".spin-container").each(function (index) {
          if (index == 0) {
            var value = "started";
          } else if (index == 1) {
            var value = "waiting";
          } else if (index == 2) {
            var value = "q1";
            var newstuff = parseInt(JSON.stringify(ed_stats[0][value]));
            var pieData = [{
                value: newstuff,
                color: "#ED4306"
              },
              {
                value: 100 - newstuff,
                color: "#F8AB00"
              }
            ];
            var myPie = new
            Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Doughnut(pieData, {
              percentageInnerCutout: 60
            });
          } else if (index == 3) {
            var value = "q2";
            var newstuff = parseInt(JSON.stringify(ed_stats[0][value]));
            var pieData = [{
                value: newstuff,
                color: "#ED4306"
              },
              {
                value: 100 - newstuff,
                color: "#F8AB00"
              }
            ];
          };
        };
      };
```

like I said, everything renders just fine, I'd just like the style the text within the doughnut. Thank you!

My (not working) JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/2nfzktzx/1/

Comment: Hi @sthig and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please submit a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I can do that, one moment

Comment: thanks @VincentOrback, I have updated with a (not working) jsfiddle.  JS is relatively new for me, I've done everything on my own not having to ask questions and finding the answers either here or Googling the answer.  This one has me stumped.  https://jsfiddle.net/2nfzktzx/1/

Comment: Hi @sthig, thank you for trying to provide us a JSFiddle. Unfortunately we were expecting a small example of your problem, not your entiere code with the ajax call etc. I have updated your JSFiddle to keep only what we need to solve your problem, but I was not able to see your problem. Can you take a look at this updated version and display your number ? https://jsfiddle.net/2nfzktzx/2/

Comment: @sthig: Please try to put your code in code tags (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) in the future to make your posts more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution of your problem.
The chart from [n3-charts](http://n3-charts.github.io/pie-chart/#/) already fullfills your requirements. Check the [examples](http://n3-charts.github.io/pie-chart/#/examples) section on the page to find some more information.

Comment: This n3-charts looks really promising.